# Can I replace the halogen H1 55w headlight bulbs on Peugeot 307 with decent LEDs?

Tags: headlight, peugeot-307

Can I replace the halogen H1 55w headlight bulbs on Peugeot 307 with decent LEDs?

I initially purchased some "xenon" (blue coated!) bulbs rated 100w but out of 4 only one worked, the other seems to break due to the soldering between bulb and its own socket. ... eBay

I am wondering if there are any LEDs that I can use instead. I had a pretty good experience with them so far but never tried them on headlights.

If not, what would you recommend? A full Xenon upgrade kit? Would it pass the MOT with them?

Comment: Did you touch the bulbs with your fingertips during installation? Headlight bulbs are very susceptible to skin oils. If you get any from your fingers on the bulbs, they will die rather quickly (within a week usually). You should use cotton gloves (preferably) or even clean/new nitrile or latex gloves will work as well. Anything to keep the contaminants off of the bulb. Just seeing if this was your issue and not the bulb itself.

Comment: I was careful, I know this trick. The soldering paste does melt on them, is clearly a very cheap product. the build still works but I need to keep it in a certain position so it would make a contact. is clearly a production defect and not a rare one, with 3 our 4 having the same identical issue.

Comment: Replacing 55W bulbs by 100W bulbs can be dangerous. Not only the wires and relays have to carry twice the current, also the housing of the light has to deal with twice the heat. 60W may be OK, but 100W? (Bright LEDs would be fine, as they may be compared to a 100W bulb while they consume just 20-40W)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case (307 series) the answer is **NO**. That's because LED lights to have to be huge to produce enough light to be similar to halogen ones and almost always you have to change the entire light-block, not only the bulbs.

Comment: Which year's variant is this? Be it any halogen projection head lamp, you can buy new glass projectors for the led and install the bulbs without worrying about any sebaceous secretions. Morimoto makes the best projectors, just put your headlamp in an oven for 3 minutes at 150 degree Celsius, remove all the silicone packing from the edges and open the head lamp apart, install the projector in the old bulb's location with the tools that come in the package, test it out without placing the cover back on, if you light what you see good, if not readjust the projector, when it settles.next comment

Comment: When you think it's right where you need the light, put the silicone paste on the edges of the plastic enclosure and seal it with the projector fitted firmly, now before it dries place it back in the oven at 200 degree Celsius for 2 minutes. Pull it out, let it dry and voila! You've got LED head lights. Remember there is always a way to get what you want. You just have to be prepared. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

GE makes a line of [Nighthawk LED headlights](http://www.gelighting.com/LightingWeb/na/consumer/products/highlights/nighthawk/led-headlights/overview/index.jsp) which might be suitable.

They claim to exceed all DOT requirements, and they also claim to be less obnoxious to oncoming drivers than HID lamps. They're promoted as being highly durable and suitable for off-road use.

Sylvania produces the [XEVO line](https://www.sylvania.com/en-us/products/automotive/ZEVO/Pages/ZEVO-LED-Sealed-Beam.aspx)

There are also many smaller companies offering LED headlights, they seem to be mostly audiophile and car enthusiast specialty sites. My main concern with a smaller company would be that they might not have reliable suppliers, so quality control might be worse. You might want to get in touch with a local car club and see if they have recommendations. LED headlight sales seem to be highly targeted at the enthusiast market.